Terraform combine if / else into one block
I am trying to configure a resource and i have two attributes that are dependent on the same bool variable, I am setting this up as below
resource "aws_sagemaker_endpoint_configuration" "ec" {
  name = "${var.model_name}-ec"

  production_variants {
    variant_name           = "${var.model_name}-ec-variant"
    model_name             = aws_sagemaker_model.model.name
    dynamic "serverless_config" {
      for_each = var.serverless ? [1]: []
      content {
        max_concurrency   = 200
        memory_size_in_mb = 2048        
      }
    }
    initial_instance_count = var.serverless == false ? var.initial_instance_count : null
    instance_type = var.serverless == false ? var.instance_type : null
  }
}

Is it possible to write the above configuration more cleanly?
if var.serverless = true I would like the serverless_config block to be set as below
serverless_config {
  max_concurrency   = 200
  memory_size_in_mb = 2048        
}

else If var.serverless=false I would like the below two attributes to be set
initial_instance_count = var.initial_instance_count
instance_type = var.instance_type


No, you have it correct.

If there are multiple independent attributes to be set, is the best way to have individual ternary checks? Seems like the for_each approach only works for block parameters.

Yes, there is no other way, unless you want to make two versions of aws_sagemaker_endpoint_configuration.
